# Reading floating-point numbers from file in COBOL

Tags: cobol, fixed-point, gnucobol

I have fixed-point numbers in file, one in each line, in this format `S9(6)V9(2)` but when they are actually read, I'm getting `non numeric` errors while trying to put them in math operations. What is more, when I try to display them in program, a number that is written in file as **567123.45** is saved in variable as **+567123.04**. And for example the number from file **123.45** is saved in variable as **+123.45.00** and it provokes the following error `'WS-VALUE' not numeric: '123.45 0'` during a math operation. Why is that?
I'm using [OpenCobolIDE](https://github.com/OpenCobolIDE/OpenCobolIDE/) 4.7.4 for Windows.

EDIT:
File has records of the following form separated by new lines (read by `READ` operation record after record):

```
  01 WS-OPERATION.
     05 WS-ID PIC A(2).
     05 WS-CLIENT PIC 9(5).
     05 WS-COUNTRY PIC A(4).
     05 WS-VALUE PIC S9(6)V9(2).
```

Comment: First: these aren't floating point items as only `USAGE FLOAT...` are floating point items. These are actually fixed point items.

Questions:
What compiler do you use? I assume the standard shipped GnuCOBOL 1.1 - If you changed the compiler paths you find this info in Menu ?->About OpenCobolIDE.
How do you read the file, how does the file and its record description look like? How does the `DISPLAY` statement look like?

Comment: Yes, I'm using version 1.1.0. I've edited the post about the file structure.

Comment: I highly suggest to edit the "floating-point" part to "fixed-point", too.

Comment: Your records are not fixed-length, are they? Even if they are, the data is "left-justified" in the field, isn't it? Can you add some actual, as it appear, full data records to your question, please?

Comment: To answer your specific question  `Why is that?`, it's because `+123.45.00` is not valid numeric; numeric field values won't have two decimal points. And it isn't in `S9(6)V9(2)` form.

Comment: @Quentin, does the provided answer work for you? If yes: please mark it as answer, if no: please comment on the answer what you miss.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that you try to un-edit a field. `567123.45` in the data is not conforming to `PIC S9(6)V9(2)` but to `-9(6).9(2).` - internal stored data vs. print-data.

Simply changing the definition and use `MOVE WS-VALUE TO WS-VALUE-INTERNAL` (which is defined like you want to) *may* work with a specific compiler (and specific data) but I'd go a different route:

I'd suggest to **always validate the data** before doing something with it (the file may be broken or external edited).
At least check the simple numeric data like `WS-CLIENT` for `IS NUMERIC` and either do a full validation on the data field `WS-VALUE` or at least use `MOVE FUNCTION NUMVAL(WS-VALUE) TO WS-VALUE-INTERNAL`.